# Class method chaining and inheritance

Tags: ruby, chaining, method-chaining, chain

I'm trying to create an ORM to wrap DynamoDB (NoSQL) queries. This ORM is inherited by models that are stored in DynamoDB. In the style of `ActiveRecord` actually:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

becomes

```rb
class User < DynamOrm; end
```

```rb
require 'aws-sdk'

class DynamOrm

    CLIENT = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new

    def find(key, options = {})
        query = CLIENT.get_item({
            table_name: 'my_table',
            key: key,
            consistent_read: true,
            return_consumed_capacity: "INDEXES"
        }.merge(options))

        if query.item.nil?
            raise 'NO ITEM FOUND'
        else
            self.new(query.item)
        end
    end

end
```

This done, I have no worries about querying on my DynamoDB database throught my ORM.

```rb
User.find({ id: 52 }) # => #<User:0x007fc5bc8a64a0>
```

It returns an instance of my `User`. I want to chain a method called `filter`. Like this:

```rb
User.find({ id: 52 }).filter({ gender: 'male' })
```

To do so, instead of returning an instance in the `find` method, I store the instance in a variable and then return the `Class`. And in my `filter` class method, I return the `User` instance.

```rb
class DynamOrm

    # [...]

    def self.find(key, options = {})

        # [...]

        if query.item.nil?
            raise 'NO ITEM FOUND'
        else
            @result = self.new(query.item)
            self
        end
    end

    def self.filter(filters)
        #
        # APPLY MY FILTERS ON `@result`
        #
        return @result
    end

end
```

I sometimes have to use `filter`, but sometimes not. Like with `ActiveRecord`, sometimes I will have to use `order` or `limit`, but not always. So, when I just want to use `find`, it will return a class instead of an instance. And a simple `User.find({ id: 1 })` will return the class `User`.

How could I reproduce the AR way, i.e., call the ORM straight on my model (`@user = User.find()`) and get an instance of this model `@user.inspect # => #<User:0x007fc5bc8a64a0 @id=1, @gender="male" >`?

Comment: I am confused, why do you fetch 1 record from database using the `find` method, and then you want to filter it by gender ? Filter only has meaning when called on multiple records, for example on result from `where` method

Comment: Anyway, there is a good reason about that in my use case regarding DynamoDB constraints. But you can transpose `find` by `where`, that won't change my needs :-)

Comment: Then you could make similar behavior like AR, when calling `where` in AR you get back `ActiveRecord::Relation`, on which you can then call `order`, `sort`, `group_by` ans so on. It does not return `User` instance nor `User` class

Comment: Thanks Nermin. May I ask you an example of how you would do it?

Comment: That is so relevant @AndreyDeineko

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to chain your query functions like ActiveRecord, you should have a class imitating the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class, which stores the pieces of request you want to make but doesn't actually query **until you perform an aggregation** (like count, sum or max) **or until you try to access the results**.

In order to make it more simple, you can just store the operations that you need at each function, and call another function at the end to perform the full query.

I imagine it like this :

```
class DynamOrm

    #Array used to store the request items before the actual request is performed
    attr_accessor :request_items

    def find(key, options = {})
        #Stores the "find" operation with its arguments in request_items
        return self
    end

    def filter(filters)
        #Stores the "filter" operation with its arguments in request_items
        return self
    end

    def perform_query
        #Actually performs the query by combining all the stored request_items
    end

end
```

And you can use it like this :
`my_results = DynamOrn.new().find(my_id).filter(my_filter).perform_query`

It might not be exactly what you need, but the idea is here : store query parameters, then query at the end.